CS8347/CS8352 with "ref struct" and "in" / "ref" parameter
I have a function with following signature
State MoveForward(in Path path);

Path is a ref struct
State is also a ref struct with just integer.
Now I have another helper function
bool TryMoveForward(in Path path, ref State state)
{
    // which does something like:
    state = MoveForward(path); // "line A"
    return !state.IsEnd(); // IsEnd determined by integer != -1
}

At the "line A" I am getting the error CS8347: Cannot use a result of 'MoveForward' in this context because it may expose variables referenced by parameter 'path' outside of their declaration scope.
But I think this shouldn't be the case or atleast compiler can be smart enough to avoid throwing this error for few reasons:

State is created just with integers (Compiler can look into the usage of path). There is no reference exposed from "path"
"State" is a ref struct which doesn't carry any "ref" to escape with.

How can I make compiler not complain about this?
I don't understand whether it is a problem of assigning something to ref State state or passing the path to in parameter.
If I remove in in MoveForward the error goes away. I want to keep the "in"
If I split the line, I don't have any way to avoid the error. eg:
    var result = MoveForward(path); // "line A"
    state = result;
    return !state.IsEnd(); // IsEnd determined by integer != -1

Getting CS8352: Cannot use variable 'result' in this context because it may expose referenced variables outside of their declaration scope.
state has its own memory in stack and result should be able to be copied to state similar to single line statement.

I cannot reproduce this. Did I misunderstand something?

@Sweeper, made a small change in your code to use "state" to update after calling MoveForward

State looks like an out rather than a ref in TryMoveForward()

@Jimi, some code are redacted. TryMoveForward also uses input from state

The State returned from MoveForward() is then what? Based on the code posted here, I assume bool TryMoveForward(in Path path, out State state) would compile. Maybe something actually relevant is missing?

@Jimi as mentioned State carries a integer. You can check the sharplab link in the comment for repro.

Based on this explanations https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/csharp-11.0/low-level-struct-improvements.md#keywords-vs-attributes
Opt out is a keyword (scoped) but the opt in is an attribute ([UnscopedRef]). So in your case you must defined it as scoped:
State MoveForward(scoped in Path path)


Is it make compiler to relax the error or it makes extra care to confirm that MoveForward function is not exposing any field from urlPathInfo?

Did few experiments and compiler provides safety with scoped keyword

@VivekMVK it isn't merely a relaxation - it is an enforced promise (in some ways it is a restriction rather than a relaxation); if you use scoped, there are things you cannot do (unless you use Unsafe etc), which you otherwise can do - such as storing a ref from the arg. But yes, scoped is what you're looking for here, and it is pretty common to see scoped crop up a lot when using ref struct. Both of these are very niche tools, and are rarely needed in "regular" code, so you might want to double-check why you're using ref struct. It isn't necessarily wrong, just: niche.
